# How to auto recompile flow-remove-types if changes is occured

Tags: javascript, webpack, loader, flowtype

It is really annoying when I should do this command before test the code:

`./node_modules/.bin/flow-remove-types --pretty --sourcemaps src/ -d dist/`

My question is there any lib or plugin to run the command when changes is occured ?

I already noticed that you can use flow type annotation with comment, by I think its not realiable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

- [Watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/)
- [Nodemon](https://nodemon.io)